# Keras: Expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (x, y)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am working on this project and can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error. I have hard-coded the training inputs and outputs, here is my entire code. I am new to writing AI code (I am an Electrical Engineering Student Researcher) so I am sorry if it looks terrible :(.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
import cmath

###train_input = [input power, tl12, tl4, rout, smith_imp]###
training_set_inputs = X = array([
    [0.001, (57.787+9.323j), (39.7-102.789j), 2000, (49.306+3.343j)],
    [0.001, (57.787+9.323j), (25.003-108.861j), 4000, (40.055+23.539j)],
    [0.001, (57.787+9.323j), (13.020-111.297j), 10000, (34.116+28.402j)],
    [1*10**-4, (57.814+9.237j), (23.708-102.443j), 2000, (49.556+22.397j)],
    [1*10**-4, (57.814+9.237j), (16.712-104.013j), 4000, (40.966+38.298j)],
    [1*10**-4, (57.814+9.237j), (10.482-105.169j), 10000, (25.069+48.663j)],
    [1*10**-5, (57.814+9.237j), (11.363-102.341j), 2000, (38.133+49.859j)],
    [1*10**-5, (57.814+9.237j), (10.285-102.579j), 4000, (31.647+54.320j)],
    [1*10**-5, (57.814+9.237j), (8.829-102.908j), 10000, (23.171+58.023j)]
])

training_set_outputs = y = array([
    [1.2*10**-12, 18*10**-9],
    [2.7*10**-12, 22*10**-9],
    [3.9*10**-12, 20*10**-9],
    [1.2*10**-12, 18*10**-9],
    [2.7*10**-12, 22*10**-9],
    [3.9*10**-12, 20*10**-9],
    [1.2*10**-12, 18*10**-9],
    [2.7*10**-12, 22*10**-9],
    [3.9*10**-12, 20*10**-9]
]).T

#Define the Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(9, 5)))

#Compile the Model
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) #binary classification

#Fit the Model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=32) #can add verbose=0 if you want to turn off training outputs

#Evaluate the Model
loss = model.Evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)

#Make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(X)

#Goal input
#array = [input power, tl12, tl4, rout, (50+0j)]
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Let me know if you see any other errors too :)
Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: Errors and hard coding aside, I am not sure if keras can handle complex number inputs. Instead, you can treat the real and imaginary parts of a feature as two separate features.

Comment: @akilat90 Okay, thanks for the advice. That was my original approach so I will go back to that. From there I still might have the same problem.

Comment: You can separate the coefficients of the real and imaginary parts into two different features. With that, you will end up with a total of 8 features in the input. Also, you will have to normalize everything before training the network for better results and if your goal is to forecast those values in the output variable, the accuracy is not the right metric. Same thing with the optimizer and loss function. The data set is TOO small. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @nemanjaone, Can you give me more details about your problem? I can't seem to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error in `tensorflow_version 1.15.2`.

You are passing incorrect `input_shape` to the model. `input_shape` is a Shape tuple (not including the batch axis), or TensorShape instance (not including the batch axis).

Modify,

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(9, 5)))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(5,)))
```

`,` after `5` is just a python notation for creating a tuple that contains only one element.

Also, as your input shape has only one dimension, you don't need to give it as a tuple, you give `input_dim` as a scalar number. Below modification also works,

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=(5)))
```

If you also want to pass the `batch_size` then modify as below,

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(5,), batch_size=9))
```

Also make sure `X` and `y` are of same length else it will throw the error. Mentioning this because you have performed `transpose` on `y`.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @nemanjaone - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.